# Changing default Path for .conda and such folders on windows

Tags: anaconda

I'm trying to install Anaconda, on Windows 7 64bits, on my hard drive D:.
However, whenever I run it for the first time, it does create .conda, .anaconda .jupyter, and so on, folders on my disk H:.

If I check the channels in the Anaconda navigator, I can see they go to H:\, but I didn't find a way to modify it.

I installed a while ago Anaconda on H, uninstalled it, and when I reinstalled it D.

I want to have everything Anaconda-Python-Jupyter related on one Hard Drive, and can't seem to manage to do so. 2 hours on google didn't help.

Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

Try set a environment variable named HOME with value point to the path where you want the dot things live.

e.g.

Say you want your .conda things move to `D:\MyWork` as `D:\MyWork\.conda`. The set the HOME variable with value `D:\MyWork`.